# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar o actualizar una registro que está relacionado con otras tablas MySQL?

Tags: python, angular, flask, webapi

Necesito eliminar o actualizar este registro para un proyecto con Angular con api en Python pero está relacionado con la tabla de facturas, y para el CRUD debo hacer que un botón elimine o actualice el registro, pero siempre arroja error o no lo elimina...

Este es el método en la API:

```py
@cross_origin()
@app.route('/delate_contact/<tabla>/<id>', methods=['DELETE'])

def delate_contact(tabla,id):
    if(tabla == "paciente"):

        columna_id = "paciId"

    elif(tabla == "odontologo"):

        columna_id = "odonId"

    elif(tabla == "factura"):

        columna_id = "facId"

    elif(tabla == "consulta"):

        columna_id = "conId"

    elif(tabla == "tratamiento"):

        columna_id = "trataId"



    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    #cur.execute("DELETE FROM "+str(tabla)+" WHERE "+str(columna_id)+" = "+str(id))

    cur.execute("DELETE FROM "+str(tabla)+" WHERE "+str(columna_id)+" IN ("+str(id)+")")

    mysql.connection.commit()



    # return mensajeRegistroEliminado(tabla)

    return jsonify({"Alerta":"Registro eliminado!"})
```

¿qué puedo hacer? he visto varias respuestas pero no sé cómo acoplarlas a lo que necesito...
¿estaría bien desvincular las tablas?